# How to get multiple columns in a single SQL CASE statement?

Tags: sql, case, informix

I'm trying to get multiple columns(insuredcode, insuredname in this case) from a single `CASE` statement.

The following query has been tried but it concatenates both insuredcode and insuredname as one column.

What is the correct syntax to return exactly two columns from such `CASE` statement?

```
select
    case
        when a.policyno[2] in ('E', 'W') then c.insuredcode || c.insuredname
        else b.insuredcode || b.insuredname
    end
from prpcmain a
left join prpcinsured_1 b on b.proposalno=a.proposalno 
left join prpcinsured_2 c on c.proposalno=a.proposalno
where a.policyno in (select policyno from policyno_t);
```

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2072721/how-can-i-select-multiple-columns-within-a-case-when-on-sql-server

Answer (score 36, accepted):

A `CASE` statement can return only single column not multiple columns

You need two different `CASE` statements to do this

```
select
    case
        when a.policyno[2] in ('E', 'W') then c.insuredcode 
        else b.insuredcode 
    end as insuredcode ,
    case
        when a.policyno[2] in ('E', 'W') then  c.insuredname
        else b.insuredname
    end as insuredname
from prpcmain a
left join prpcinsured_1 b on b.proposalno=a.proposalno 
left join prpcinsured_2 c on c.proposalno=a.proposalno
where a.policyno in (select policyno from policyno_t);
```

Comment: any ideas if the query engine optimizes something if conditions are same in both cases

Answer (score 5):

I can suggest something else that might be slightly faster :

```
SELECT s.insuredcode,s.insuredname FROM (
    SELECT a.policyno,b.insuredcode,b.insuredname
    FROM prpcmain a
    left join prpcinsured_1 b on b.proposalno=a.proposalno 
    WHERE a.policyno[2] not in ('E', 'W')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.policyno,c.insuredcode,c.insuredname
    FROM prpcmain a
    left join prpcinsured_2 c on c.proposalno=a.proposalno 
    WHERE a.policyno[2]  in ('E', 'W')
) s
where s.policyno in (select policyno from policyno_t);
```

As to your question, [@Prdp](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39941910/5353753) shows what you need to do.

Answer (score 5):

> It is simply like if/else condition in any language, you can define your condition in **When** statement and if it is true, SQL executes the **Then** statement, otherwise executes **Else** part, as described below:

```
     Select 
                 CASE 
                    WHEN (cs.ResultSubmitToHOD = 1) THEN 'HOD'
                    WHEN (cs.ResultSubmitToExamDep = 1) THEN 'Exam'
                    ELSE 'Teacher'
                END AS ResultSubmitStatus
     From dbo.CourseSection as cs
```

Comment: This does not answer the question, which is not only asking for yielding two columns, but also has a specified SQL dialect: Informix.

Comment: I think @luqman-cheema just misunderstood the question, as frankly I did too. I came here looking for this answer, actually :) So, the original question above wants two columns IN THE RESULT, and this answer is talking about using two columns within the CASE IN THE QUERY...

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks !  (even though someone voted you down)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for as well!